# Angular routing for different layouts

Tags: angularjs, express, angularjs-routing

How do I load different layouts ?

Currently I have three layouts for my backend, one for `admin`, one for `user` and last for `teacher` i.e `adminLayout.html`, `userlayout.html` and `teacherLayout.html` for dashboards.

I am writing my routes something like this -

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/users/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/users/login.html',
            controller: 'usersLoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/users/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/users/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'usersDashCtrl'
        })
        .when('/teachers/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/teachers/login.html',
            controller: 'teachersLoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/teachers/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/teachers/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'teachersDashCtrl'
        })
});
```

For `/users/dashboard` I want `usersLayout.html` and `/teachers/dashboard` I want teachersLayout.html.

How could I acheive this ?

I tried `$window.location.href = "LINK_TO_LAYOUT";` but its is taking the whole path in the URL, however I want to my URL like -

```
mysite.com/teachers/dashboard
mysite.com/users/dashboard
mysite.com/admin/dashboard
```

Comment: Why not use ui-router? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: @diproart I checked the doc but could not find anything thr regarding different layout calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Ui-Router.

It support nested views.

So in your example your routes would be like this.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/pages/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .state('users', {
        url: '/users',
        templateUrl: 'views/users/layout.html'
    })
    .state('users.login', {
        url: '/users/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/users/login.html',
        controller: 'usersLoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('users.dashboard', {
        url: '/users/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/users/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'usersDashCtrl'
    })
    .state('teachers', {
        url: '/teachers',
        templateUrl: 'views/teachers/layout.html'
    })
    .state('teachers.login', {
        url: '/teachers/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/teachers/login.html',
        controller: 'teachersLoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('teachers.dashboard', {
        url: '/teachers/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/teachers/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'teachersDashCtrl'
    })
});
```

Then you need to creat this new Layout Pages.
On: views/users/layout.html

```
<div id="usersLayout">
    <ui-view/>
</div>
```

On: views/teachers/layout.html

```
<div id="teachersLayout">
    <ui-view/>
</div>
```

Hope this get you going.

Answer (score 1):

One of ways use '**abstract**' state from [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-state-usage-examples)

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts', {
    abstract: true,   // <<< this is your layout
    url: '/contacts',

    // Note: abstract still needs a ui-view for its children to populate.
    // You can simply add it inline here.
    // >>> Or use templateUrl: 'contactLayout.html'
    template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state('contacts.list', {
    // url will become '/contacts/list'
    url: '/list'
    //...more
})
.state('contacts.detail', {
    // url will become '/contacts/detail'
    url: '/detail',
    //...more
})
```

Please spend some time for learning ui-router and you will have powerfull and simple tool for routing in angularjs.
[Check docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-state-usage-examples) for more info about abstract state.